# Mysql pivot table check same column for two value at the same time

Tags: mysql, pivot, case, where-clause

I have pivot table with the following structure:

```
|  keyx  |  value |  name  |  id  |  form_no  |
-----------------------------------------------
| hour   |   01   |  Ali   |   12 | 100000001 |
-----------------------------------------------
| min    |   00   |  Ahmad |   17 | 100000001 |
-----------------------------------------------
| hour1  |   03   | John   |   21 | 100000001 |
-----------------------------------------------
| min1   |   01   | Mike   |   33 | 100000001 |
-----------------------------------------------
| hour   |   01   | Homa   |  76  | 100000002 |
-----------------------------------------------
| min    |   02   | Omid   |  73  | 100000002 |
```

Now i want to select `name,id,form_no` from table(my_table) but check if `keyx = 'hour' and value = '01' and keyx = 'min' AND value = 'oo' and form_no = '100000001'`. SO how can i use may be `WHERE CASE` or `WHERE IF` for this. Thanks for any guide and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
select name,id,form_no from table(my_table) where keyx in ('hour','min') and value in (01,00) and form_no= 100000001;
```